# Find Replace Hotkeys In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Anyone know of a set of hotkeys that can perform a find/replace in eclipse?

Currently the flow looks like:

1. Select line or lines
2. Ctrl+F
3. Type phrase
4. TAB
5. Type replacement

And then I have to do the unthinkable and grab my mouse, choose selected lines and then click on replace. It doesn't sound like much, but it seriously disrupts my flow when i'm doing a bunch of word replacement. I wish their was a way to choose "selected lines only" and "replace all" using keystrokes only besides having to hit TAB 12 times. Or maybe i'm using the wrong tool within eclipse for this sort of thing...

**Using Ubuntu and Eclipse Luna 4.4.2**

Comment: It is windowing system related, because on Windows you have Alt+t (lines) Alt+r (replace).

Answer (score 2):

Using Find/Replace for *refactoring* seems like a smell. You should instead use the refactoring operations

- Rename : Alt + Shift + R
- Extract constant : Alt + Shift + K
- Extract method : Alt + Shift + M
- Extract variable: Alt + Shift + L
- Inline : Alt + Shift + I
- Change method signature : Alt + Shift +C
- Introduce indirection
- Introduce parameter object

and so on, which all do a kind of replacement by themself, but always work on the syntax tree and not on the text. However, the refactoring support depends much on the language used in the project, and while Java has really good support in Eclipse, this might not be the case for other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I had been trying for this for a long time and ended up in multiple pages without help. I figured it out myself after playing around

For the first time, you need to do the below

1. Ctrl + F - to open the search box on the top right corner of the IDE (as in image)
2. You might have to drill down (using the small icon on the left of the search box) to see the replace text

This setup stays from now onwards.
Now you can simply use

- Ctrl + F, Tab, Alt+Shift+Enter combinations to do the search and replace

I use **eclipse 2020-03** on windows. I am pretty sure many of the previous releases had the same functionality on linux as well.

Screenshot of the feature:

[image]

Comment: how did you get this?? Tried but gets a dialog instead. Eclipse 2021-3 on windows. Maybe thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found thath `ctrl+K` works in my ide (Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) on windows)

First use `Ctrl+f` to set a term for search, then use `ctrl+K` to move to next.

If you need to replace something, keep in the clipboard the text and use `ctrl+K`, `ctrl+v`.